# How do i navigate to search keyword occuring above current line in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

In visual studio, I used to use chrl+shift+f to navigate to keyword occurrence above the current line. How do I do that in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Select the “word” and use “**ctrl+shift+k**”